# radius of convergence of $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: power-series

$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$
After a bit of experimenting with geometric series, it seems the radius of convergence  is restricted because the function blows up at $x=1$.

If I do the power series about a different point, say $x=100$, the [radius of convergence increases to 99](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%201%2F%281-x%29%20at%20x%20%3D%20100). The farther I pick the point, the larger the radius of convergence!

Extrapolating this, can I say the power series of continuous functions like $\sin x, \cos x, e^x$ etc should have *infinite* radius of convergence?

Comment: @JMoravitz: But if you plug $x=10$ into the series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ about the point $x=100$, it converges. Did you click on the link in the question?

Comment: If $x$ were $10$, then the sum converges if we did the power series about any point greater than $9$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. This is a $C^\infty$ function defined everywhere in the real line. It has no singularity but the radius of convergence at $x=0$ is $1$.
The explanation lies in the complex plane. The radius of convergence is the distance to the closest singularity.

Comment: cool example! ty:) do you mean when $x=i$ it blows up?

Comment: @rsadhvika, exactly. It's the standard example.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302167/radius-of-convergence-iff-distance-to-the-nearest-singularity and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362626/who-said-the-shortest-trajectory-between-two-realities-is-complex

Comment: Just to clarify: $\sin x$, $\cos x$ and $e^x$ _do_ have an infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: I don't know complex analysis :( if we consider complex singularities too, can we say the radius of convergence is infinite if the function doesn't blow up ?

Comment: Oh I think you've answered my question already - *radius of convergence is the distance to the closest singularity*

Comment: @rsadhvika: If the function is infinitely differentiable in the complex plane, then yes, its radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: @TonyK right! Im just watching this short vid on why $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ has such small radius of convergence. Surprising how complex numbers kick in XD https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7-vejtX7vo

Comment: @TonyK I know all polynomials are infinitely differentiable even though the tails become $0$. Isn't $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$  also infinitely differentiable ?

Comment: @rsadhvika: not at $x=1$.

Comment: Ohk saying "infinitely differentiable"  means "infinitely differentiable everywhere" gotcha!  Playing in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jbzblrh3oz) for $1/(1+x^2)$, if we imagine $i$ on y axis at $y=1$, then the power series about $a$ will have the radius of convergence  $\sqrt{1+a^2}$. This is because the circle cannot go beyond the points $z=\pm i$ in complex plane. Hope I got this right. Thanks again:)